# How to use dplyr to calculate the mean of column values?

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr

I'm using dplyr in my R script which is being called by a SQL Server stored procedure.  The query output I'm analyzing is as follows:

[image: columnnar responses]

My R script and TSQL query thus far are:

```
sqlQuerySensory <- "Select
        c.StudyID, c.RespID, c.ProductNumber, c.ProductSequence, c.BottomScaleValue, 
        c.BottomScaleAnchor, c.TopScaleValue, c.TopScaleAnchor, c.StudyDate,
        c.DayOfWeek, c.A, c.B, c.C, c.D, c.E, c.F,
        c.DependentVarYN, c.VariableAttributeID, c.VarAttributeName, c.[1] as c1, 
        c.[2] as c2, c.[3] as c3, c.[4] as c4, c.[5] as c5, c.[6] as c6, c.[7] as c7, c.[8] as c8
        from ClosedStudyResponses c
        --Sensory Value Attributes only for mean and standard deviation analytics.
        where VariableAttributeID = 1
        and c.StudyID = 21"

 x = sqlQuerySensory

 codemean <- function(x) {
   '%>%' = magrittr::'%>%'
   dplyr::group_by(x, .data$code)
   dplyr::summarize_at(dplyr::vars(dplyr::matches("c\\d+")), mean)
   return ()
 }
 result <- codemean(x = x)

 OutputDataSet <- result$x
```

The R Interactive window displays the following errors:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class 
"character"
Error: object 'result' not found
```

How do I modify my dplyr script to produce the average of column c3 for a given set of responses?

UPDATE:
I've corrected much of the script using feedback from comments received and documentation as well.  I also used a static StudyID for testing purposes and now receive a full summary for each column in my query.  The revised TSQL syntax is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCodeMeans]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StudyID int,
@StudyID_outer int OUT


AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Declare @inquery nvarchar(max) = N'Select
        c.StudyID, c.RespID, c.ProductNumber, c.ProductSequence, c.BottomScaleValue, 
        c.BottomScaleAnchor, c.TopScaleValue, c.TopScaleAnchor, c.StudyDate,
        c.DayOfWeek, c.A, c.B, c.C, c.D, c.E, c.F,
        c.DependentVarYN, c.VariableAttributeID, c.VarAttributeName, c.[1] as c1, 
        c.[2] as c2, c.[3] as c3, c.[4] as c4, c.[5] as c5, c.[6] as c6, c.[7] as c7, c.[8] as c8
        from ClosedStudyResponses c
        --Sensory Value Attributes only for mean and standard deviation analytics.
        where VariableAttributeID = 1
        and c.StudyID = 21'
        ;
BEGIN TRY

        exec sp_execute_external_script
        @language = N'R',
        @script = N'
            OutputDataSet = data.frame(summary(InputDataSet))',
@input_data_1 = @inquery

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
END
```

Based on my stored procedure above, how do I return the mean for columns c1 through c8 grouped by StudyID?

Comment: I'm having a hard time making sense of the code you've written. Can we remove the TSQL stored procedure from the equation at all? Have you written some dplyr code just in R that queries the db and performs some simple operations on it? If you don't mind my asking, how much R/dplyr code have you written before this? I'm just trying to get a handle on where you're coming from here.

Comment: I don't think the issue is in your dplyr script, but in your assignment to `sqlQuerySensory`. That entire block is just a string, rather than specifying attributes for a data frame (which is what I'm guessing you're going for there). I don't see anything that looks like a data table in your code, thus the trouble applying `group_by`. Unless I'm missing something in your question?

Comment: To clarify, I'm hesitant to leap into any attempts at help here because, to me, almost none of that code looks even remotely valid to me, which makes me wonder if I'm missing something about how R code is executed inside of SQL Server...?

Comment: @phalteman Thanks for pointing this out.  Besides setting up the columns from my SQL query in a data.frame, are there any other changes you suggest?

Comment: @joran The above code was originally written in R Studio.  My goal and intent is to port it over for use in SQL Server R Services by using it within a TSQL stored procedure.  Taking the first step by working with the syntax in Visual Studio before creating the actual stored procedure.

Comment: So, this code ran without errors and returned a result when you ran it in RStudio?

Comment: @joran I'm unsure whether it returned results.Unfortunately, it was inherited from another developer.

Comment: Well, assuming again I'm not missing something about how R code is executed when run inside of SQL Server, here are things I don't understand about this code: (1) There's no code that actually sends the query to the db. Typically this would involve the DBI package. (2) `codemean()` ends with the statement `return()` which normally in R would mean that it would always return nothing. (3) 3 of the lines of `codemean()` make no assignments to a variable; the results of that code would be lost (4) I can't find where `.data$code` would come into existence. I could go on...

Comment: Before jumping into writing a function, I'd recommend simplifying things in order to do some debugging. See if you can execute your query and get back a dataframe. The error about `group_by` is that the input to your function is a string (the query), rather than the dataframe returned by executing the query. Get that much working before abstracting it into a function

Comment: I'll leave it to others to comment on the TSQL code. I don't see edits to the R code, but I second @camille 's advice to greatly simplify it to get that part to work. Then you'll know whether the problem is there or in the query result. For the R side, I'd construct a small dummy data frame that looks like the one you expect, and break `codemean()` into step-by-step calls to ensure each line does what you want. @joran is right that as is, `codemean()` will lose any products because there are no assignments, and it returns nothing, so that's a place to start.